# Using VLOOKUP formula or other function to compare two columns

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, date

I have one table like this:

```
SHORT TERM BORROWING 
1/6/2009    94304
12/31/2010  177823
6/30/2011   84188
12/31/2011  232144
6/30/2012   94467
9/30/2012   91445
12/31/2012  128523
3/31/2013   83731
6/30/2013   78330
9/30/2013   70936
12/31/2013  104020
3/31/2014   62345
6/30/2014   62167
9/30/2014   63494
12/31/2014  104239
3/31/2015   69056
```

I have another column which lists each date from 2009 to 2015 in chronological order, like:

```
1/2/2009
1/3/2009
1/4/2009
1/5/2009
1/6/2009
1/7/2009
1/8/2009
1/9/2009
1/10/2009
1/11/2009
1/12/2009
1/13/2009
1/14/2009
1/15/2009
1/16/2009
1/17/2009
1/18/2009
1/19/2009
1/20/2009
1/21/2009
1/22/2009
1/23/2009
1/24/2009
1/25/2009

...

6/22/2015
```

I am trying to write a function that will take the values from the first table, and match them to their corresponding dates in the chronological dates column. Basically, I want the second column, which lists each date in chronological order, to have a value of "94304" for "1/6/2009", and then blanks until it reaches 12/31/2010, where it should have a value of 177823, and so on until 6/22/2015. I have tried using VLOOKUPs but no luck so far. What is the appropriate function?

Comment: Why should 1/2/2009 have the value of 94304 when it is listed as 1/6/2009 in the first table?  Or is this just a small typing mistake?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo, thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data in your first table starts at A2, and your other column starts at D2, then use in E2

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$17,2,0)
```

Copy down as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I like Sancho.s' answer. I would include an IFERROR in your solution, so that if there is no answer corresponding to your search, you will not get #N/A.

Assuming your SHORT TERM BORROWING table is in columns A and B, and the dates you are searching are in column D, then the formula in column E would be:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

This assumes that you want a blank cell as opposed to 0 in a cell that returns no value. If you want something else in there, replace the "" with another value.